# <p> tag not working in <div>

Tags: html, alignment, paragraphs

I am trying to add the word "Invitations" to the top right of the page aligned with the "back to photos" link. However, when I add a new `<div>` then start a `<p>` the paragraph does not align to the page properly at all once I apply CSS.

I have uploaded the page where I am having trouble: http://ashliamabile.com/invitations.html

Comment: Sounds like you need to float your "back to photos link" left, the new text div right, and then clear the mainContainer div:(#maincontainer{clear:both;}

Comment: Can you post the basic idea of what you're doing? Without seeing the CSS and HTML, it's hard to know where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

#### HTML:

```
<div id="backtophotos">
    <a href="print.html"><img src="images/backprint.png" border="0"></a>
    <p class="title">invitations</p>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
/*Drop the width property and set div to position:relative */

#backtophotos {
    height: 20px;  /* removed width */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0 0 0 100px;
    position: relative;  /* set positon to relative */
}

/* Set title p to position absolute and remove margins: */

.title {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

The above works because the div width is already "set" by the outer div, so you only need to worry about where the top right corner actually is if you change the layout.  Otherwise, float-free right-aligned header.

Also, the only reason I explicitly set my margins to 0 for the `.title` is because `p` elements have their top and bottom margins set (and I think line-height). If you changed the `p` to a `div` (your choice, and a `p` has some value of being more explicitly meant for text), then your `.title` rule would just be:

```
.title {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

which is exactly what you are looking for without any additional tricks or tweaks (which is the name of my halloween rap album).

Personally, I would actually go with something more like:

```
<div id="backtophotos">
    <h2><a href="print.html">back to print</a><h2>
    <h2 class="title">invitations</h2>
</div>
```

And deal with clearing all of the default browser css, as the above would be most semantic. I would also advise not using the image for your "back to print" text and explore one of the many [`CIR`](http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/) methods out there, as a screen reader won't be able to read the image aloud.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id="backtophotos">
   <a href="print.html"><img src="images/backprint.png" border="0"></a>
   <p>invitations</p>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
#backtophotos p{
  float:right;
} 
#backtophotos a{
   float:left;
}
#backtophotos{ /*Clear float : any one of this method - micro clearfix, clearfix,  overflow method, float, clear both */ 
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: If you use this code, you'll need to make sure you update the width on #backtophotos from the current 130px to something larger or 100%...

Comment: Only if we give #backtophotos float property. #backtophotos is a block level element so even if we don't give it a width. It will stretch 100%.

Comment: In the example link, there's already a width set on #backtophotos of 130px.  All I'm saying is this would need to be updated to something larger (or 100%) in order for your code to work...otherwise they'd be stacked on top of each other.

Comment: I don't see a `p` tag in there.  Did the example page change or are we just assuming the `p` follows the `a`?  The OP mentioned adding a new `div`.

Comment: You can replace p with div. P is a new addition here.  That's why I didn't added width also. Its just a sample. Shown is the bare minimum code to create desired effect.

Comment: For sure. In fact, div would be better (in some ways) since `p` elements come with build in margins and line-height.  I gave another answer that uses positioning instead of floats.